# Calculate Time Logic rounding to nearest factor c#

Tags: c#

I have two properties of time stamp without AM/PM. What's needed is to find the total time spent in quarter unit determined by _factor. Then there is a rounddown & roundup concept which is determined by _roundDown value as cut off point. Finally, returning a decimal value back after the calculation.

This resides in a class definition that sets up a property TotalTime. Because of this reason, I would like the code to be efficient. Excuse my code as this is the last piece of the project and want to get it done.

How can I improve the code: I am using mod calculation.

```
private decimal ComputeTotalTime(int _increment)
{
decimal _TotalHours = 0;
int _roundDown = 7, _factor = 15;
int int_TotalHours = 0;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(StartTime) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(EndTime)) return _TotalHours;

DateTime timeFromInput = DateTime.ParseExact(StartTime, "H:m", null);
DateTime timeToInput = DateTime.ParseExact(EndTime, "H:m", null);

//Here found a problem that we need to ensure that EndTime is greater than StartTime
//In one run, StartTime is 10:30 and EndTime is 2:32 
//but the DateTime variables took is as 10:30 PM and 2:32 PM hence producing negative difference

TimeSpan ts = timeToInput.Subtract(timeFromInput)
int_TotalHours = ts.Hours * 60 + ts.Minutes;

if (int_TotalHours % _factor == 0) {        /*I'm Perfect, no need to round*/    }
else if (int_TotalHours % _factor <= _roundDown) { 
        //Round down to nearest 15th, quarter
        int_TotalHours = int_TotalHours - (int_TotalHours % _factor); }
else {  //Round up to nearest quarter
        int_TotalHours = int_TotalHours + (_factor - int_TotalHours % _factor); }

_TotalHours = Convert.ToDecimal(int_TotalHours / 60.00);
_TotalHours = (_TotalHours * 100) / 100;

return _TotalHours;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I would like the code to be efficient" Is it being hit thousands of times a second? Is it correct? How often does the code get hit? If the answers are no, yes and infrequently, move on an do something more important!

Comment: This likely belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As you can see the code return negative difference bcz 10:30 becomes 10:30 AM and 2:30 becomes 2:30 AM instead of PM. Greatest start with small steps.